# Turtles move to nearest patch of a certain color - how can this process be sped up?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to build a butterfly movement model in which butterflies are attracted to patches of their host plant.  This attraction is expressed as a probability which is stored in a variable called "attr-prob". If a butterfly is located within 25 m of a host-plant patch (pcolor = 9.9), it will move to the nearest host-plant patch with the probability of attr-prob.

I wrote the following code:

```
if (distance (min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = 9.9]) [distance myself]) )     <= 25 
 [if random-float 1 < attr-prob [move-to min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = 9.9]) [distance myself]]]
```

This code seems to be doing what I want it to do, however, when I add this part into my model, it slows it down immensely.  Does anyone have any alternative suggestions for coding this that might be quicker?

I am running Netlogo in 64-bit Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if random-float 1 < attr-prob [
  let target-patch min-one-of (patches in-radius 25 with [pcolor = 9.9]) [distance myself]
  if target-patch != nobody  [
    move-to target-patch
  ]
]
```

This should be faster for a couple reasons.

First, the fastest code is the code that never runs. So, doing the probability check at the very beginning allows you to skip computing the closest patch whenever you can.

Second, using `in-radius` upfront rather than checking the distance at the end reduces the number of patches that you're looking over. Basically, you'll only be checking the color and distance of the patches in the radius, rather than all of the patches in the world.

Finally, in your original code, you were finding the closest patch twice. Instead, you can store the patch in a local variable (`target-patch` in the code I provided) so you only have to find it once. This alone should double the speed of the code (depending on the value of `attr-prob`). It also increases readability.

Comment: Thanks! This sped the model up quite a bit.

Comment: Happy to hear it! If you feel like this answers your question, make sure to mark it as correct by clicking the check mark so others know that this question has been answered.